# Open an unsaved text file

Tags: vb.net, process.start

In my vb.NET project I have a reference to a "content" resource called `check_output.txt`.
In the code I open this file, write in it and then show the file in the default text editor. The code I use is this:

```
Dim FILE_NAME As String = Application.StartupPath & "\" & "check_output.txt"

If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then

    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)

    objWriter.Write(txtOutput.Text)
    objWriter.Close()

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(FILE_NAME)
Else

    MsgBox("Impossibile trovare il file di testo di default", vbCritical, "Errore")

End If
```

I would like to treat the txt file as a temporary file, so it will always be empty except when I write in it. But I don't want to allow the user to save in it, so when he close the file a "SaveAs" dialog should appear. After the closing the file should return empty. Is this tricky to obtain? How can I do this?

In other words I want the editor to act as when you do "File->New"... So you have a temp file, not stored in the harddisk.

Comment: Do you really need to open the editor? What about a form with a textbox in it? Then you can control what actions should be done when closing it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I already have the textbox with the output. Then I have 3 buttons for export in Excel, Word and .txt. Excel and Word open themselves and show the output (formatted). The document is unsaved so the "SaveAs" dialog appears on closing the application (even if I have a bug, see my previous question). I want to replicate this behavior with the text editor.

Answer (score 1):

1. Write your data to the file and save it.
2. Change the properties of the file to "Read-Only" (this will disallow "Save" in most editors and only allow "Save As".
3. After the user completes their work (or closes the application, or whatever), reset the file properties and clear the file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If the user doesn't modify the file content the "SaveAs" dialog doesn't appear... This is not what I want to achieve.
I want the editor to act like when you do "File->New"... So you have a temp file, not stored in the harddisk.